# How to save data in variable for JQ?

Tags: jq

JQ Play example
https://jqplay.org/s/wPDeHoMBxS

**Goal**

I have multiple rows(20) of data for a unique name with different dates.
I want to have a single row with the name, date of the first row, and the date of the 20th row.

```json
{"pos":1,"date":"2020-12-04","name":"ABC"}
{"pos":2,"date":"2020-12-03","name":"ABC"}
.
.
.
.
{"pos":20,"date":"2020-11-04","name":"ABC"}
```

The expected output in the given example.

```
"\"2020-12-04\",2020-11-04,\"ABC\""
"\"2020-12-04\",2020-11-04,\"DEF\""
```

Comment: Would something like `jq -r '[.name, .date]|@sh' FILE | sed -n '1p;20p'` work?

Comment: @InianThanks for the info. I will take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `group_by()` function for this. First by `.name` and then `sort` by the `.date` field. Try running the expression below with one pipeline at a time to visualize how each function takes shape.

```
[ inputs ]        | 
group_by(.name)[] | 
sort_by(.date)    | 
[ last, first ]   | 
[ .[0].date, 
  .[1].date, 
  .[0].name 
]                 | 
@csv
```

Working demo at [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/qJAEx4tvDD)

or if the requirement is strictly look for the object with `.pos` as 20, do an explicit `select()`

```
[ inputs ]        | 
group_by(.name)[] | 
sort_by(.date)    | 
map(select(.pos == 1 or .pos == 20)) 
[ .[0].date, 
  .[1].date // "", 
  .[0].name 
]                 | 
@csv
```

The shorthand `// ""` updates an empty string, in case the `.date` field is not available for lookup.

Comment: This can work, Though I need another chance. What if there is no 20th position? In such cases, I would like it to be an empty value.

Comment: Edit: got it. using  ```[last, .[19]]``` solved the issue